# How to apply start and finish positions to jquery parallax animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what I have currently.

I need to add a layer of detail though. What I would like is from 0-1000px for there to be NO increment in opacity and then from 1000-1500 to fade from 0 to 1 opacity.

How can I do this?

Use this: ([woking jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5Z8M/1/))

```
function EasyPeasyParallax() {
    scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('#nav').css({
            'opacity': 0+(Math.min(scrollPos/800,1))
        });
};

$(function(){
    $('body').bind('mousewheel',EasyPeasyParallax);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with css3 in HTML5 browser support:

```
@-webkit-keyframe{ /* for chrome browser */
 0%{
 }
 50%{
 }
 100%{
 }
}
@keyframe{ /*do the same for other browser */
 0%{
 }
 50%{
 }
 100%{
 }
}
```